# Change to a relative color on hover in modern CSS

Tags: css, colors, background-color

I want react to hovering on a link:

```
/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none ;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted ;
}
```

…to alter slightly the background color around the text. Rather than specify a certain color, I want to just **lighten or darken whatever the inherited color** as currently set. For `hover` and `active` on a link, I want the background color to change, to give something of the effect of a button being pressed.

I want to be able to alter the background color of the text or page without having to alter the specific color in the `a:hover` rule too.

Comment: SCSS can do the lighten or darken of colours so you can say "lighten($color, .2)" to lighten a colour by 20%.You could set the background colour as a different lighten, or darken, percentage of the original colour to keep the ratio consistent between the hover and the background. More on SCSS here: https://sass-lang.com/. Or you can use CSS variables:

Comment: @NathanielFlick Thanks for the tip. I am hoping to do this in straight CSS if possible.

Comment: CSS doesn't have colour functions, but it does have colour variables. SASS compiles to CSS so basically the same thing. :)

Comment: You may want to see `filter: brightness()`, though this alters the color of the text rather than the background color.

Comment: @k-a-v For `hover` and `active` on a link, I want the background color to change, to give something of the effect of a button being pressed.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `filter: brightness()`, although you also have to specify a particular color on the body background and background of `a` to be `inherit`. The default value of `background-color` is `transparent` and cannot be darkened. It needs to be changed to `inherit` to get a particular color so that darkening can work. If it is transparent, the alpha is 0 and is not subject to darkening or brightening.

However, if the link is inside a `div` and the `div` doesn't have a specific background color, then it'd be transparent, and the link would inherit that background color.  So the link needs to have a particular background color to be darkened.

I did a `window.getComputedStyle($0)["background-color"]` where the `$0` was the `div` selected in the developer's console, and the result was `"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"`, meaning transparent.

```css
body { background: white }

a { background: inherit; border-radius: 2px }

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
    filter: brightness(.8);
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

For such scenarios, I typically utilize [HSL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/hsl()) color values. This eliminates the need to manually copy colors across multiple elements, as you can easily adjust the ***lightness*** component of the color.
HSL color model is more human-readable than Hex code ([`#F37022`](https://fromkato.com/color/f37022)).

> HSL color values are specified with: `hsl(hue, saturation, lightness)`.

```css
a {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  color: white;
}

.color {
  --hue: 22;
  --saturation: 90%;
  --lightness: 54%;
  background-color: hsl(var(--hue), var(--saturation), var(--lightness));
}

.color.light:hover {
  --lightness: 80%;
  /* 20% light */
}

.color.dark:hover {
  --lightness: 40%;
  /* 20% dark */
}
```

```html
<a class='color light'>Hermès</a>
<a class='color dark'>Hermès</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

> …to alter slightly the background color around the text.

If you want the color exactly around text then [text-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow) can be used:

```css
a {
  font: bold 2em serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: inherit;
}

a:hover {
  text-shadow: 1px 0px 2px #000, 1px 0 9px #000;
  /* text-shadow: 1px 0px 2px #000, -1px 0 2px #000; */
}

a:active {
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #000, 1px 1px 2px #000;
  color: #fff8;
  filter: contrast(20) opacity(0.5);
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: white; color:blue ">
  <a href="#">One</a>
  <a href="#">Two</a>
  <a href="#">Three</a>
</div>
<div style="background-color: wheat; color:#D06224 ">
  <a href="#">One</a>
  <a href="#">Two</a>
  <a href="#">Three</a>
</div>
<div style="background-color: lightgreen; color:#172774">
  <a href="#">One</a>
  <a href="#">Two</a>
  <a href="#">Three</a>
</div>
<div style="background-color: lightseagreen; color: lightsalmon">
  <a href="#">One</a>
  <a href="#">Two</a>
  <a href="#">Three</a>
</div>
```

The shadow automatically gets blurred depending on the `blur-radius` and blends with the background. You don't have to provide extra opacity.
On hover I am darkening the area around the text and on click(active), I am making text transparent so that it takes background color.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, this is not possible with css alone. You could use preprocessing like SASS.

Then you could shift hue using `filter` rule.

Lastly, probably what you wanted, there is `color-mod()` rule in works, but I haven’t heard of it lately.

Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-4/

---

PS: I did remember to sometimes use:

```css
a {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}

a:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .8);
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
}

div + div {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div><a>Hover me, darken</a></div>
<div><a>Hover me, lighten</a></div>
```

Comment: Pre-processing with SASS only outputs CSS so it is entirely possible with CSS alone.

Comment: @Rob, having JS in page will also end up with CSS there... the point is you will have to do some additional overhead to have this working, unlike the `color-mod()` function that would run out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider an extra layer above the background where you apply white or black coloration to make the background lighter or darker:

```css
a {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px;
  color:#fff;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.red {
  background:red;
}
.blue {
  background:blue;
}
.green {
  background:green;
}
.light:before,
.dark:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  opacity:0;
}
.dark:before {
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

a:hover::before {
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<a class="red light" href="">some text here</a>
<a class="red dark" href="">some text here</a>
<a class="blue light" href="">some text here</a>
<a class="blue dark" href="">some text here</a>
<a class="green light" href="">some text here</a>
<a class="green dark" href="">some text here</a>
```

A similar idea without pseudo element

```css
a {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px;
  color:#fff;
}
.red {
  background:red;
}
.blue {
  background-color:blue;
}
.green {
  background:green;
}

.light {
  background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.3),rgba(255,255,255,0.3));
}
.dark {
  background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.3),rgba(0,0,0,0.3));
}

.light,
.dark {
  background-size:0 0;
}

a:hover {
  background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<a class="red light" href="">some text here</a>
<a class="red dark" href="">some text here</a>
<a class="blue light" href="">some text here</a>
<a class="blue dark" href="">some text here</a>
<a class="green light" href="">some text here</a>
<a class="green dark" href="">some text here</a>
```